# studying the topology of a real algebraic set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-topology

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ be polynomials with real coefficients and let $I$ be the ideal that they generate. Denote by $V_{\mathbb{R}}(I)$ the corresponding real variety, i.e. $V_{\mathbb{R}}(I)=V_{\mathbb{C}}(I) \cap \mathbb{R}^m$.

Main question: What are the tools that i can use in order to study the topology of $V_{\mathbb{R}}(I)$ induced by e.g. the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}^m$? More specifically, i need to perform computations in order to determine the number of connected components and possibly find equations that describe them. Note that i already have my hands on the book "topology of real algebraic sets" by Akbulut and King, however, after skimming through it, i still have no ideal how to proceed.

Side question: is it true that an algebraic set is the union of connected components in the metric topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that instead of studying real algebraic sets, it is more natural to study real *semialgebraic* sets, i.e. those defined by systems of polynomial equalities and inequalities. You can find some tools for studying the topology of real semialgebraic sets described [here](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/SAG.pdf). The most useful, as far as I recall, are CAD (Cylindrical Algebraic Decomposition) and a theorem that any real semialgebraic set $X$ is homotopy-equivalent to $X\cap B(0,r)$, where $B(0,r)$ is the open ball around $0$ of radius $r$, for sufficiently large $r$ (IIRC there is an effective upper bound on $r$).

To answer your side question, all subsets of a metric space are unions of their connected components. For real semialgebraic sets we can do better: they have only finitely many connected components.